# Can't get document.getElementById.getElementsByTagName to work properly

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function confirm_results(theform) {

var inputsX = document.getElementById(theform).getElementsByTagName('textarea');
          for(var iX = 0, nX = inputsX.length - 1; iX < nX; iX++)
          {
            text += inputs[iX].innerHTML + ', ';
          }
return text;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I'm trying to find all of the textarea's inside a DIV that I pass the name through, and return the text. Some reason it just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is not the right way to read a textarea's value.

Partly because any `<` or `&` characters in it will be HTML-escaped, but mostly because the text node content inside an `HTMLTextAreaElement` node is not indicative of the current value of the textarea.

In fact the text node content is the original content of the textarea as seen in the HTML source. This is the same as the `defaultValue` property. It does not get updated when you type in the textarea... except in IE which as usual gets it all wrong.

You probably want to use `inputs[iX].value` instead.

The same goes for normal inputs, where `input.value` represents the current value but `input.getAttribute('value')` is the same as `input.defaultValue`, representing the original value put in the `value="..."` attribute in the HTML source. Again: except in IE due to more bugs.

The same again applies to the `checked` and `selected` properties of checkboxes and select options: the `checked` and `selected` *attributes* are the original values reflected in the `defaultChecked` and `defaultSelected` *properties*.

Also, with the `length-1` you're ignoring the last textarea in the list. Do you really mean to do that?

Comment: Works for me, post fuller example? (Note in the snippet posted so far you have not initialised `text` to `''`, so if run as-is without additional code you'll get an error when you try to `text+=` anything.)